# Using LINQ to find a common prefix?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I've got two sequences:

```
IEnumerable<string> x = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
IEnumerable<string> y = new[] { "a", "b", "d", "e" };
```

I'd like to find the common prefix of these two sequences (i.e. `"a", "b"`). Is there a succinct way to do this in LINQ?

Bear in mind that these aren't really `IEnumerable<string>`; they're `IEnumerable<PathComponent>`, where I have an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<PathComponent>`.

Comment: Hmm, 4.0 gets Zip for this. Something like x.Zip(y).TakeWhile(t => t.Item1 == t.Item2).Select(t => t.Item1);

Comment: +1 yeah Zip would do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dykam's mention of Zip led me to this code:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public delegate bool EqualityComparison<in T1, in T2>(T1 x, T2 y);
    public delegate bool EqualityComparison<in T>(T x, T y);

    public static IEnumerable<T> CommonPrefix<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> xs,
        IEnumerable<T> ys)
    {
        return CommonPrefix(xs, ys, EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> CommonPrefix<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> xs,
        IEnumerable<T> ys,
        EqualityComparison<T> eq)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> x = xs.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<T> y = ys.GetEnumerator();

        while (x.MoveNext() && y.MoveNext() && eq(x.Current, y.Current))
        {
            yield return x.Current;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> CommonPrefix<T1, T2, TResult> (
        this IEnumerable<T1> xs,
        IEnumerable<T2> ys,
        EqualityComparison<T1, T2> eq,
        Func<T1, T2, TResult> selector)
    {
        IEnumerator<T1> x = xs.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<T2> y = ys.GetEnumerator();

        while (x.MoveNext() && y.MoveNext() && eq(x.Current, y.Current))
        {
            yield return selector(x.Current, y.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, made imperative, put in a Extension method. Should have done that myself. I actually made ZipSelect for own use in some Rest lib.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I don't know about the performance of the Skip() on the second array:

```
x.TakeWhile((s, i) => y.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault() == s);
```

Edit: Oops - here's a slightly better approach:

```
x.TakeWhile((s, i) => y.ElementAt(i) == s);
```

Comment: @Matt: Tried that; works except that you need to ensure that 'y' is the longer of the two sequences...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this (not tested):

```
x.TakeWhile((item, index) => y.Contains(item) && y.IndexOf(item) == index);
```

**EDIT**. IndexOf is available only on arrays, so you should convert y to an array first. Also, you need to modify the code to use your IEqualityComparer.